# Remove all characters after regex - Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a date that looks something like this "9/22/2015" but sometimes its like any one of these:

```
"9/22/2015 1"
"9/22/2015 ee"
```

So I am checking in Java with regrex like this

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})");
if (patt.matcher(start).find()) {
      System.out.println("match");
}
```

But these "9/22/2015 1", "9/22/2015 ee" are also matching? And what I want to do is check for just "9/22/2015" and then anything after that just get rid of, no matter what it is how could I do this?

I also tried `Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})");` but it also came true for "9/22/2015 1", "9/22/2015 ee"

Thanks

Comment: They match, of course, but use end anchors, like `^` and `$` to anchor the match to both ends, like in `"^([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)$"` and they will not mach anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use `matches()` instead of `find()`

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})");
if (patt.matcher(start).matches()) {
      System.out.println("match");
}
```

- `matches()` will try to match the full string
- `find()` will scan the string until one match is found

Comment: do you mean `.matches()`?

Comment: great thanks and then how could I remove any thing that comes after it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `"^([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})$"`

It should work with `.find()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're want to use a [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) (and [`match.group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group--) specifically) to extract the captured group:

```
    String start = "\"9/22/2015 1\"";
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})");
    Matcher match = patt.matcher(start);
    if (match.find()) {
        System.out.println(match.group()); // prints: 9/22/2015
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need that nothing follows your date, then tell to regexp that there is a new line \n or end of line $ after your date, or maybe some extra space. Check \n for multi lines and $ for multi line and in case of 1 line/string. Actually you told to regexp that find string which looks like that date format. It found it. You did not tell to regexp that what can or what can not be after that.